# Mongodb array in array

Tags: php, arrays, php-mongodb

This is my mongo doc, how  can i get hud to object or array where $_id = ("52ee9fef94ffc1f7a0dd0a55") in PHP?

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("52ee9fef94ffc1f7a0dd0a55"),
 "lvl" : 2,
 "required_xp" : 100,
 "rewards" : {
         "hud" : [
                 {
                         "type" : "food",
                         "amount" : 50
                 },
                 {
                         "type" : "soft",
                         "amount" : 100
                 }
         ],
         "inventory" : [
                 {
                         "id" : 24,
                         "amount" : 1
                 }
         ]
 },
 "xp_next_lvl" : 110
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question better. Would you like to know how to select a specific doc from your collection by the id?

Answer (score 0):

To select only the `rewards.hub` field for the document matching a specific `_id`, you can use `findOne` with a projection:

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('mydb');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'mycollection');

    // Search criteria
    $query = array('_id' => new MongoId("52ee9fef94ffc1f7a0dd0a55"));

    // Projection (fields to include)
    $projection = array('_id' => false, 'rewards.hud' => true);

    $hud = $collection->findOne($query, $projection);
    var_dump($hud);
?>
```

Sample output of `var_dump` (tidied for readability):

```
array(1) {
  ["rewards"] => array(1) {
        ["hud"] => array(2) {
              [0] => array(2) {
                    ["type"] => string(4) "food"
                    ["amount"] => float(50)
                  }
              [1] => array(2) {
                    ["type"] => string(4) "soft"
                    ["amount"] => float(100)
                  }
            }
      }
}
```